# Failed to load .net binary on IDA Pro

Tags: ida, .net

I tried to use IDA Pro to load a binary file. IDA detected it as a .NET file:
[image]

but when I click OK to load the program, the following error occured, and the program can't be loaded:
[image]

I tried to google the error message, but found no answer. Please help me to load this file. Thanks!

Comment: why about dnSpy? maybe the file is intentionally broken to prevent it from being analyzed?

Comment: Or IDA is too old for this binary. IDA 7.0 was released in 2017...